# Deserialize & Serialize. Как правильно это делать с ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, realm, realm-database

Есть json файл в котором есть geopoints ArrayList - 
"geopoint":[76.8958,43.2775]. 
В Realm нельзя хранить ArrayList, для этого я создал отдельную модель для него:

Model - **GeopointResponse:**

```
public class GeopointResponse extends RealmObject {

   private float lat;
   private float lng;

   public float getLat() {
       return lat;
   }

   public void setLat(float lat) {
       this.lat = lat;
   }

   public float getLng() {
       return lng;
   }

   public void setLng(float lng) {
       this.lng = lng;
   }
}
```

**Вот я пытался написать Deserialize:**

```
    public class GeopointDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<GeopointResponse>, JsonSerializer<GeopointResponse> {
    @Override
    public GeopointResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Float lat = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsFloat();
        Float lng = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsFloat();
        GeopointResponse eventGeopoints = new GeopointResponse();
        eventGeopoints.setLat(lat);
        eventGeopoints.setLng(lng);
        return eventGeopoints;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(GeopointResponse src, Type typeOfSrc,   JsonSerializationContext context) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Не знаю как написать Deserialize & Serialize для данного json вида: "geopoint":[76.8958,43.2775].  Прошу помочь.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "id": "583bc78233f2763f927ad731",
  "interests": [
    {
      "id": "583bc77d33f2763f927ad474",
      "parent": null,
      "local_cities": [],
      "title": "Изобразительное искусство",
      "is_global": true,
      "is_active": true
    },
    {
      "id": "583bc77d33f2763f927ad476",
      "parent": null,
      "local_cities": [],
      "title": "Современное искусство",
      "is_global": true,
      "is_active": true
    }
  ],
  "city": {
    "id": "583bc77e33f2763f927ad495",
    "country_name": "Казахстан",
    "is_active": true,
    "name": "Алматы",
    "geopoint": [
      76.8958,
      43.2775
    ]
  },
  "currency": {
    "id": "583bcfd633f276475e4746cf",
    "name": "Kazakhstani tenge"
  },
  "author": {
    "id": "583bc77e33f2763f927ad497",
    "fn": "happerala@happapp.info"
  },
  "start_datetime": "2015-11-12T00:00:00",
  "end_datetime": "2015-12-15T00:00:00",
  "is_upvoted": true,
  "is_in_favourites": false,
  "images": [
    {
      "id": "583bc78233f2763f927ad732",
      "path": "/uploads/media/583bc78233f2763f927ad731/91adc85f338512b89a18e8528601aa211449650928.jpg",
      "color": "#595959"
    }
  ],
  "date_created": "2016-11-28T05:58:26.080000",
  "date_edited": "2016-11-28T05:58:26.080000",
  "title": "Персональная выставка Паоло Пиби",
  "description": "В Esentai Gallery продолжает свою работу персональная выставка молодого итальянского художника Паоло Пиби Fake Golden Age (\"Фальшивый Золотой век\").\r\n\r\nРаботы, представленные на выставке объединяют две вещи. Первая – узнаваемый авторский стиль: постоянное обращение к двум визуальным и тематическим планам, один из которых скрывает другой, отвлекает от него внимание, но именно скрытый план выступает источником первого, питает его и на границе между ними рождается мираж, поглощающий зрителя, выводяший его в пространство вне времени. Вторая – нарочитая высокая цитатность представленных работ: какие-то угадываются легко, какие-то то требуют напряжения – художник предлагает зрителю погрузиться в контекст живописи 20 века, сравнить её с современной, взглянуть на обе критически, и в конце концов – вступить в культурный диалог с самим автором, угадать его собственное отношение к источникам вдохновения – от пиетета до тонкой иронии.",
  "language": "en",
  "type": 0,
  "status": 1,
  "min_price": null,
  "max_price": null,
  "address": "Esentai Gallery, ТРЦ Esentai Mall, пр. Аль-Фараби 77/8",
  "place_name": null,
  "geopoint": null,
  "phones": [
    "+7 (727) 330-88-77"
  ],
  "email": null,
  "web_site": "http://www.esentaimall.com/",
  "votes_num": 1,
  "close_on_start": false,
  "registration_link": null,
  "min_age": 0,
  "max_age": 200
}
```

Comment: прикрепите небольшой кусок этого файла, а не 1 пример, пожалуйста.  при сериализации это важно

Comment: @SeniorAutomator какого именно файла? Json?

Comment: да,  json файл, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorAutomator дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator мне тот, который связан с событием, а не с городом.